# Twitter Bootstrap 3: How to get vertical navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Seems like it was supported in [v2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs) in form of class `.nav-stacked`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
  ...
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do that in version `3.0.0`?

Comment: You mean, only by using Bootstrap's classes?

Comment: It's still supported in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Looks like it's still in 3.0 -- http://bootply.com/86667

Comment: Thats not a navbar, thats a nav.

Answer (score 5):

The default `nav` class in Bootstrap 3 has a vertical layout (no borders though), also `.nav-pills` still support the stackable layout, but if you want the "old" look you can always just add the styles from the previous version to your CSS (plus a small fix):

```
.nav-stacked > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-stacked > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
/*Fix to remove space between li's*/
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked>li+li {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li > a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li:first-child > a {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li:last-child > a {
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li > a:hover,
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap 3.0 still contains a [`nav-stacked`-class](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills). if it's mising in your copy, just [get the latest version](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) or add this to your css-file:

```
.nav-stacked > li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-stacked > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```